# Rails is not precompiling javascripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I just started a working on an existing project and I'm running into some problems with getting jquery to load on localhost. The deployed site seems to be working fine so I'm kind of stumped as to where to start to troubleshoot this issue.

In the console I'm getting:

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined localhost

It seems like jquery isn't loading, but it is included in the gemfile.

In the console the base.js file shows up like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require sass-bootstrap-3/dist/js/bootstrap
//= require modernizr
//= require respond
//= require lodash
;
```

Where I think it should be showing the complied version of the scripts.

Running this in the console shows that jquery is indeed there.

```
Rails.application.config.assets

--- !omap
- :enabled: true
- :paths:
  - /Users/000/app/assets/ebooks
  - /Users/000/app/assets/fonts
  - /Users/000/app/assets/images
  - /Users/000/app/assets/javascripts
  - /Users/000/app/assets/stylesheets
  - /Users/000/vendor/assets/javascripts
  - /Users/000/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  - /Users/000/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/client_side_validations-3.2.6/vendor/assets/javascripts
  - /Users/000/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/coffee-rails-3.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  - /Users/000/.gem/ruby/2.0.0/gems/jquery-rails-3.0.4/vendor/assets/javascripts
  - !ruby/object:Pathname
    path: /Users/000/app/assets/fonts
- :precompile:
  - !ruby/object:Proc {}
  - !ruby/regexp /(?:\/|\\|\A)application\.(css|js)$/
  - !ruby/regexp /(^[^_\/]|\/[^_])[^\/]*$/
  - !ruby/regexp /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
- :prefix: /assets
- :version: '1.0'
- :debug: true
- :compile: true
- :digest: false
- :manifest:
- :cache_store:
  - :file_store
  - /Users/000/tmp/cache/assets/
- :js_compressor:
- :css_compressor: !ruby/object:Sass::Rails::CssCompressor
    options:
      :style: :compressed
- :initialize_on_precompile: true
- :logger:
- :compress: true
- :digests: {}
- :source_digests: {}
```

I'm using Rails 3.2.5 and jquery-rails 3.0.4. 
Any ideas on where to start troubleshooting this? I've already spent a day trying to solve this (probably very simple  fix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you also try http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.19/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets? It might help to check your settings on precompiling assets.

Beyond that, could it be that you are missing the line `//= require jquery_ujs`? 
https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails specifies both `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs`.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by doing two things:

first: downgrade to ruby 1.9.3 and 
second: as was suggested above, add 
   `//= require jquery_ujs`
to the manifest js file

Thanks for your help.